# What could be generally the type of error when you see a message "nameofyourc++program has stopped working"?

Tags: arrays, windows

I'm new to C++ and I have discovered this problem recently where I'm not able to run my program (it's able to compile successfully with showing 0 errors). When i run, my system shows  a message saying "merging2arrays.exe has stopped working" and then optioning to either stop the program and to check solutions. And either way, the program closes.

Please help.

Comment: As far as I know there is no "genrally" here. This error message is very generic and the most probable causes depends on what your code is actually doing. For example if you access read a file it could be that the file isn't in the right location, if you write to it it could be you d'ont have the rigths, and so on. So to give you a more accurate answer we would need to at least see your code. If that code is too big, you would need to narrow it down.

Comment: We cannot really help if your don't show your source code (and your compilation command). Please edit your question to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully about [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow), [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) and perhaps [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) & [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) & [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) (actually rule of 5).

Learn and use [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) at least (or C++14), not some earlier standard. This could mean configuring your compiler (e.g. with `-std=c++11`) and using a *recent* compiler.

I would advise to avoid using raw C++ arrays (like `int arr[37];`). If possible, prefer [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) or [std::array](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/).

Compile your program with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). Improve it till you get no warnings. Then learn how to **use the debugger**